# Similar isosceles triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

$ABC$ and $ADB$ are similar isosceles triangles, such that $BC: CD = x : y$

I am told that the area of $ABC$ : area of $ADB$ = $x$ : $x + y$, but I cannot see intuitively why this would be the case?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it does not matter similar or isosceles. They have a common vertex $A$ and equal height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a perpendicular from $A$ onto $BD$ and note that it also serves as a perpendicular for the other triangle.